# How do I find the bearing of where an object will be?

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to figure out how to find the bearing of where an object will be in the future. I know the objects current `bearing`, `heading` and `velocity`. I know that I have to adjust the bearing based on the heading and velocity for a given amount of time, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

The its `bearing` is the degrees clockwise from North (0) from my position. Its `heading` is its direction of travel, again degrees clockwise from North (0) and its `velocity` is meters in 0.2 seconds.

Any idea how I can do this?

Basically given the information, I need to turn to where the object will be, not to where it is currently.

Comment: You don't have enough information. You need `bearing` and `distance` to determine the current location. Then `heading`, `velocity`, and `time` can be used to compute the new position. Once you know the new position, you can compute the new `bearing` and `distance`. Things get more complicated if the object is accelerating, decelerating or turning.

Comment: There is no way to do this without position? It seems I should be able to do with without knowing its position.

Comment: A simple example should dispel that notion. Imagine an object 5m away from you. If it moves 10m, it could theoretically end up at any bearing. On the other hand, if it's 5000m away, and it moves 10m (in any direction), the bearing won't change by any significant amount.

Comment: But I know its heading and given the velocity and time I know the distance it travels on its heading.

Comment: @Justin808 Could you show a picture/sketch to make this question more clear?

Comment: @Justin808 you absolutely need to know *how far away it is to start with*. If it's 1mm away and moves 1m its bearing will likely change a LOT. If it's 1km away and moves 1m its bearing will definitely change VERY LITTLE.